# Specifying sort order in a JSON API

Tags: javascript, api, json-api

My team recently adopted the [json api convention](http://jsonapi.org/). In the documentation for the api sorting is not addressed.

They do however address [filtering](http://jsonapi.org/recommendations/) in the recommendations page but in my opinion, sorting is not part of filtering since filtering is used to reduce a set while sorting is used to re-order a set.

**Given the json api convention, I'd like to know:**

- Should sorting be the responsibility of the api or the client?
- If it should be the responsibility of the api, are there any guidelines for structuring the url to handle sorting?

Comment: Api should always be the one with that responsability.  T-sauer already posted the answer, just use sort.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Sorting is actually documented on the website: http://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-sorting

Short summary:

- use `sort` as the parameter name
- if you need to sort by multiple attributes, comma separate them (e.g. `sort=lastname,forename`
- if you want to specify the order, use a plus or minus in front of the attribute name (e.g. `sort=-lastname,forname`), the default order is ascending

Comment: Thanks for this. I can't believe I missed it in the documentation.