# Specifying sort order direction in a JSON API

Tags: java, api, json-api

Does Restful API define proper ways to give Sort Order Direction,  (Ascending or Descending) for API user parameters ?

I am letting a user input a request string, that only allows two options for API to work "Ascending" or "Descending" . Is there a more formal way of doing this per standards?

Request:

```
{
  "sortField": "PaymentDate",
  "sortOrder": "Descending"
}
```

[Specifying sort order in a JSON API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41315891/specifying-sort-order-in-a-json-api)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [JSON:API specification](https://jsonapi.org/) specifies that sorting order is ascending by default. Client could switch the sorting order by prefixing the sort field with a minus (`-`).

> The sort order for each sort field MUST be ascending unless it is prefixed with a minus (U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS, “-“), in which case it MUST be descending.
>
> https://jsonapi.org/format/1.1/#fetching-sorting

Your example given does not look as if your API implements the JSON:API specification. Even though this question is tagged with `[json-api]`. If you API does not implement the JSON:API specification, you are free to design the API for controlling sorting order as you like.

The [API specification of the OpenStack project](https://specs.openstack.org/openstack/api-wg/index.html) could give an inspiration. It also uses a comma-separated list of sorting fields: `?sort=key1,key2,key3`. A client may specify the sorting direction by appending either `asc` or `desc` to the sorting field using colon (`:`) as a separator: `?sort=key1:asc,key2:desc,key3:asc`. If sorting direction is not specified, then the server can chose sorting direction.

> Sorting is determined through the use of the ‘sort’ query string parameter. The value of this parameter is a comma-separated list of sort keys. Sort directions can optionally be appended to each sort key, separated by the ‘:’ character.
>
> The supported sort directions are either ‘asc’ for ascending or ‘desc’ for descending.
>
> The caller may (but is not required to) specify a sort direction for each key. If a sort direction is not specified for a key, then a default is set by the server.
>
> https://specs.openstack.org/openstack/api-wg/guidelines/pagination_filter_sort.html#sorting